# Delete Rows of custom UITableViewCell frame issue

Tags: ios, tableview, cell, frame, uitableview

I am relatively new to Xcode and Swift programming, and in my first app, which consists of a tableview with a custom TableViewCell which overrides the variable frame to not cover the full width of the view:

```
override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }

        set {
            var frame = newValue
            frame.origin.x += 175
            frame.size.width -= 350
            super.frame = frame
        }
    }
```

Everything works as expected, but when I delete a Tableview Cell with `self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [path], with:  .automatic)`, a strange issue with the cell appears; it looks like the cell again gets a new (smaller) frame than the old one, but only the visible cells; if the cells get reloaded, the issue is gone. So it just happens right after the delete; if the cell leaves the screen and is then presented again, it goes back to its normal size. 
My guess is that `newValueis already a custom frame and then gets customized again which makes it even smaller; but I have no idea how to adress this issue!

Here are screenshots from the iPad version:

[Normal tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnBI5.png)

[After deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifAoH.png)

Any help will be appreciated! If you need further information, please let me know in the comments! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you **not to interfere in cell's frame** the way you do.

1. Set cell's `backgroundColor` to `UIColor.clear`
2. Create a custom view on cells's `contentView`, horizontally centered and 350 points narrower then the cell itself.

Or

1. Make the whole tableView's `width` 350 points less then screen width
2. Forget about changing cells's `width`

For the first suggestion view hierarchy and autolayout constraints will look similar to this:

[image]

> The problem is with a custom view I will run into even more troubles
>   because the height of each cell is different from one another

That's another topic altogether. You should use dynamic cell height, described in detail in this [RayWenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells)

Basically, you need to set autolayout constraints properly and do this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
```

**Discouraged approach:**

> My guess is that `newValueis already a custom frame and then gets
>   customized again which makes it even smaller; but I have no idea how
>   to adress this issue!

If you still want to use your approach, **don't just decrement the value**, calculate it from scratch using `UIScreen`'s or `tableView`'s `width`

Instead of this

```
frame.origin.x += 175
frame.size.width -= 350
```

Do this:

```
frame.origin.x = 175
frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 350
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your detailed answer! From my point of view the first suggestion makes the most sense to me, but could you provide me with some starting code how and where to make this custom view on the contentview? I haven't done this in a while... Thank you!

Comment: @EliasDatler Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Yes, whenever I can. @alexburtnik

Comment: Oh, I got it, your last suggested approach works perfectly!! so probably the problem was I didn't calculate the views width from scratch... Thank you very much man! I really appreciate

Comment: You're welcome. See the updated answer for more details on first approach.